# Error message when installing Open Office 4.1.1

Tags: software-installation, openoffice.org

I'm cut & pasting the commands to install OpenOffice. I removed LibreOffice and downloaded OpenOffice fine, but when I put in the command to extract OpenOffice, I get this error message:

```
z: Cannot open: No such file or directory.
```

I can see the Apache folder in my files. What's the problem?

Comment: Can you add the exact command you're using? It's saying you didn't enter the correct path to the file.